# Convert/query array into JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a SELECT query that results in something like this:

```
USER_ID: 000030 USERNAME: Oprah RATING: 5
USER_ID: 000033 USERNAME: Pitbull RATING: 8
```

What I need is to display it in this form:

```
[[{"USER_ID":"000030","USERNAME":"Oprah","RATING":"5"},{"USER_ID":"000033","USERNAME":"Pitbull","RATING":"8"}]]
```

Generally I get this desired result with this SELECT:

```
try {
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT USER_ID, USERNAME, RATING FROM table");
  $stmt -> execute(array($userid));
  while($row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $output[] = $row;
  }
}
print(json_encode($output));
```

But this time I had to get the result in this form:

```
try {
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT USER_ID, USERNAME, RATING FROM table");        
  $stmt -> execute(array($userid));
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    //$output[] = $row;
    $row2[$i][$j] = $row['USER_ID'];
    $j++;
    $row2[$i][$j] = $row['USERNAME'];
    $j++;       
    $row2[$i][$j] = $row['RATING'];
    $i++;
    $j=0;               
  }
}
```

How can I convert it into the desired form or form the query to produce it?

I tried these:

```
print(json_encode($row2));
[["000030","Oprah","5"],["000033","Pitbull","8"]]

$output[] = $row2;
print(json_encode($output));
[[["000030","Oprah","5"],["000033","Pitbull","8"]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `json_encode()` to produce a json string that includes the associative indices, they need to be in the array you are encoding. If the indices are 0, 1, 2, etc., the indices will not show up in the json string.

Try this:

```
$i=0;
while(...) {
    $row2[$i]['USER_ID'] = $row['USER_ID'];
    $row2[$i]['USERNAME'] = $row['USERNAME'];      
    $row2[$i]['RATING'] = $row['RATING'];
    $i++;
}
...
print_r(json_encode($row2));
```

Consider [**this PHP snippet**](http://codepad.org/42X2qEPi) for clarification.

---

Alternative methods of building array:

```
while(...) {
    $row2[] = array(
        'USER_ID' = $row['USER_ID'],
        'USERNAME' = $row['USERNAME'],
        'RATING' = $row['RATING']
    );
}

// OR

$i=0;
while(...) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
        $row2[$i][$key] = $val;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Mark, this results in [{....}, {...}], but I need [[{...},{...}]]. So I added `$output[] = $row2;
print(json_encode($output));` and now it's working. Thanks!

Comment: @erdomester No problem, simply put `$row2` into an array. Try: `print_r(json_encode(array($row2)));` See [**Demo**](http://codepad.org/QZc6jW0V)

Comment: @erdomester Oops didn't see your edit until after posting my last comment. That works too!! Glad you got it working! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $output[] = array("USER_ID" => $row["USER_ID"], 
                     "USERNAME" => $row["USERNAME"], 
                       "RATING" => $row["RATING"],
                     );
}
print(json_encode($output));
```

Comment: Hi. This isn't my area of expertise, but your answer came up in a review queue. Mainly because it's just a block of code with no explanation. It's generally a good idea to explain what you wrote and why it solves the original problem. Don't forget that heaps of newbies come to Stack Overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from you - what may be an obvious solution to you is not to them. So please be kind :)